# How to fix the size of text in bounding box?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, easyocr

I am new to computer vision. I am struggling to fix the size of the bounding box around the text.

Here is the sample code

```
#extracting text using easyocr
    output = reader_hi.readtext('/content/drive/MyDrive/hindi_image.jpg')

    #translating words to other indian languages
    #removing text from images 
    
    #this is the code where I am pasting the translated words
    image = Image.open("image.jpg")#text removed from the image
    
    #red color
    color = (0, 0, 255)
    thickness = 1 
    
    fontpath = "/content/drive/MyDrive/ArialTh.ttf"
    TEXT_Font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 16)
    
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    
    i=0
    
    for bound in output:      
      tl, tr, br, bl = bound[0]
      
      tl = (int(tl[0]), int(tl[1]))
      tr = (int(tr[0]), int(tr[1]))
      br = (int(br[0]), int(br[1]))
      bl = (int(bl[0]), int(bl[1]))
    
      
      draw.text(tl, translation[i], font = TEXT_Font, align='left', fill='black') 
      i=i+1      
        
    image.save('image_translation.jpg')
```

[image: translated image]

[image: Glimpse of the bounding box around the text]

I would like to resize the bounding box to same size. So that when I paste the translated text it would be aligned in one line.

Can I do some changes in this part so that the translated text will be aligned in one line

```
for bound in output:      
      tl, tr, br, bl = bound[0]
      
      tl = (int(tl[0]), int(tl[1]))
      tr = (int(tr[0]), int(tr[1]))
      br = (int(br[0]), int(br[1]))
      bl = (int(bl[0]), int(bl[1]))
    
      
      draw.text(tl, translation[i], font = TEXT_Font, align='left', fill='black')
```

Is there some other way to make the text fall in one line.

Comment: You can try morphological operations using a horizontal kernel that would join all words in a line as a single entity

Comment: @JeruLuke Can you explain in more detail please

Comment: @JeruLuke Can you please tell me where and how can i edit the code to join all the words in a line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528380/how-to-get-coordinates-of-the-overall-bounding-box-of-a-text-image