# How to get coordinates of the overall bounding box of a text image?

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract, pytesser

original image

[image: original image]

img = cv2.imread('eng2.png')

```
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
n_boxes = len(d['level'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(img)
```

The above code produces this image. Now in the image there are two coordinates one for each word and other for the whole text. I would like to get the coordinates for the whole text (sentences in each line or the whole paragraph

[image: The above code produces this image. Now in the image there are two coordinates one for each word and other for the whole text. I would like to get the coordinates for the whole text (sentences in each line or the whole paragraph)]

This is what I have tried

```
box = pd.DataFrame(d) #dict to dataframe
box['text'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True) #replace empty values by NaN
box= box.dropna(subset = ['text']) #delete rows with NaN 

print(box)


def lineup(boxes):
    linebox = None
    for _, box in boxes.iterrows():
        if linebox is None: linebox = box           # first line begins
        elif box.top <= linebox.top+linebox.height: # box in same line
            linebox.top = min(linebox.top, box.top)
            linebox.width = box.left+box.width-linebox.left
            linebox.heigth = max(linebox.top+linebox.height, box.top+box.height)-linebox.top
            linebox.text += ' '+box.text
        else:                                       # box in new line
            yield linebox
            linebox = box                           # new line begins
    yield linebox                                   # return last line

lineboxes = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lineup(box))
```

Output dataframe

[image: Output dataframe]

```
n_boxes = len(lineboxes['level'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    (x, y, w, h) = (lineboxes['left'][i], lineboxes['top'][i], lineboxes['width'][i], lineboxes['height'][i])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(img)
```

There seems to be no difference between the original coordinates and after joining all the coordinates

[image: There seems to be no difference between the original coordinates and after joining all the coordinates]

How can i get the coordinates of the whole text (sentences in each line or the whole paragraph) using pytesseract library?

Comment: Maybe change your approach using exclusively OpenCV. Pre-process the image with some morphology. Apply a dilation with a large structuring element to join the text in blocks/paragraphs. Find external contours on this image and get the bounding rectangles of the blobs. Also, please, include your original unprocessed image.

Answer (score 1):

You faced a similar issue in one of your previous questions [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72463211/how-to-fix-the-size-of-text-in-bounding-box). I failed to elaborate what I meant in the comments. Here is a more visual explanation.

By horizontal kernel I meant an array with single row `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`. The number of columns can be determined based on the **font size** and **space between characters/words**. Using the kernel with a **morphological dilation** operation you can connect individual entities that are present horizontally as a single entity.

In your case, we would like to extract each line as an individual entity. Let's go through the code:

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread('letter.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# inverse binary image, to ensure text region is in white
# because contours are found for objects in white
th = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

[image]

Now there is a black border surrounding the original image. In `th` it becomes are white border. Since it is unwanted we will remove it using `cv2.floodFill()`

```
black = np.zeros([img.shape[0] + 2, img.shape[1] + 2], np.uint8)
mask = cv2.floodFill(th.copy(), black, (0,0), 0, 0, 0, flags=8)[1]
```

[image]

```
# dilation using horizontal kernel
kernel_length = 30
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_length, 1))
dilate = cv2.dilate(mask, horizontal_kernel, iterations=1)
```

[image]

```
img2 = img.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for c in contours:
  x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
  img2 = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,255,0), 2)
```

[image]

You can get the coordinates for each line from `cv2.boundingRect()`. This can be seen in the image above. Using those coordinates you can crop each line in the document and feed it to `pytesseract` library.

Comment: I got the entire rectangle letter. I copied your code.

Comment: one whole rectangle instead of multiple rectangles.   cv2.imshow*"letter', img2)

Comment: @toyotaSupra Thanks for spotting it. The change is made while applying threshold `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` not `cv2.THRESH_BINARY`